# how to change the order of resampling in python timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a the following python pandas timeseries

```
index = pandas.date_range('4/1/2012','9/30/2012', freq='M')
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(len(index),1), index=index)
df = 
2012-04-30 1.06
2012-05-31 0.82
2012-06-30 0.65
2012-07-31 1.12
2012-08-31 1.09
2012-09-30 0.65
```

Then i change the frequency from one month to two months

```
df_new = df.resample('2M')
```

The resample function start from the earliest date to last date. The output that i get is as follows:

```
df_new = 
2012-04-30 ...
2012-06-30 ...
2012-08-31 ...
2012-10-30 ...
```

whereas i want the algorithm to resample in the reverse order. I want the output something like this:

```
df_new = 
2012-05-31 ...
2012-07-31 ...
2012-09-30 ...
```

Could anyone please help with this.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is more complicated than it should be - but here goes

```
In [282]: df
Out[282]:
                   0
2012-04-30  0.583255
2012-05-31 -0.247403
2012-06-30  0.816290
2012-07-31 -1.989587
2012-08-31  0.740463
2012-09-30  0.971749


In [279]: df.resample('2M', how='last', closed='left', loffset='-1M')
Out[279]:
                   0
2012-05-31 -0.247403
2012-07-31 -1.989587
2012-09-30  0.971749


how='last' gets last value in group
closed='left' forces first date[2012-04-30] to be the start of the group (maybe side effect)
loffset='-1M' adjust label appropriately
```

Comment: oh hmm...actually rereading the question i think you're right that `loffset` is not sufficient, you need both how='last' and loffset. I wish the question contained the desired data alignment too so it was clearer.

Comment: how='last' helps, but doesn't solve the problem entirely. This is because resampling is assuming the first date[2012-04-30] is the end of the time period[6M]. If this could be controlled by a parameter, it would solve the question

Answer (score 1):

Use the `loffset` parameter:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                   0
2012-04-30  0.667305
2012-05-31 -1.353332
2012-06-30  0.132986
2012-07-31 -0.697344
2012-08-31 -1.043487
2012-09-30 -0.050352

In [9]: df.resample('2M', loffset='M')
Out[9]:
                   0
2012-05-31  0.667305
2012-07-31 -0.610173
2012-09-30 -0.870416
2012-11-30 -0.050352
```

Comment: please see user1827356 answer below, you actually need both loffset and how='last' here

Answer (score 0):

These things tend to be a lot trickier then you would first expect. I agree with Chang that it would help to have a very clear example of how the exact alignment should be. Note that it also matters that the input data in the example also has a monthly frequency. The final alignment off the above mentioned solution changes for example if the input frequency is days, see:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('4/1/2012','9/30/2012', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': index, 'Doy': index.dayofyear}, index=index) 

df.resample('2M', how='last', closed='left', loffset='-1M')

                           Date  Doy
2012-04-30  2012-05-30 00:00:00  151
2012-06-30  2012-07-30 00:00:00  212
2012-08-31  2012-09-29 00:00:00  273
2012-10-31  2012-09-30 00:00:00  274
```

Alternatively the 'MS' frequency can be used, creating yet another approach:

```
df.resample('2MS', how='last', loffset='2M')

                           Date  Doy
2012-05-31  2012-05-31 00:00:00  152
2012-07-31  2012-07-31 00:00:00  213
2012-09-30  2012-09-30 00:00:00  274
```

It all comes down to how you would define the start and end of a bin.